# Really weird sci-fi movie I saw as a kid

Tags: story-identification, movie

The movie in question, I think may have had a title referencing some sort of container, but I could be wrong.

It starts out with a group of criminals meeting a scientist out in the middle of nowhere to take possession of a mysterious package. The scientist warns them not to open it. They take the package back to their hideout, and start to bicker about what to do with it. To be clear, they're just supposed to be holding on to it for a while, until the scientist can reclaim it.

They eventually open it, and find a strange creature inside. They decide they should sell it for money, but the creature begins telepathically manipulating them and causing strife. They begin to fight amongst themselves, culminating in all but one of the criminals being killed. The one woman left, is then telepathically compelled to have sex with the strange creature. Weirdest sex scene, ever.

I'd really like to know the name of this movie, or at least some approximations of what the title might be, as I'd like to find out more about it. I should mention, I probably would've been around 10 or 11 years old when I saw it, making the year I saw it sometime in the mid 2000s. And I think the movie was relatively old, even then, as it was a VHS tape, and looked like it had been made in the 70s or 80s. Again, any help is appreciated.

Comment: What happened after the sex scene? Was that nearly the end of the movie? the Middle? or just the beginning?

Comment: The weird sex scene was basically the end.

Answer (score 10):

"The Item" (1999)?

Here is the plot summary from IMDb.com

> Four felons are contacted by an anonymous client via the internet.
>   They are instructed to go to a remote desert island and pick up an
>   "item" and keep it safe for 24 hours. It will then be picked up and
>   they will be paid. However, upon getting it back to their apartment,
>   their curiosity gets the better of them and they decide to investigate
>   their package. They discover that they have a telepathic worm
>   connected to a life support system. The film then disintegrates into a
>   slasher film as one by one the protectors are killed in grisly
>   fashion.
>
> —John Sacksteder

You can also view the entire movie on YouTube, but I'm just not wanting to post it here.

Comment: Looking at the Trailer, that looks like the Cheesiest B-movie ever made. But it certainly seems like the movie the OP described. Double checked the movie on YouTube and I am sure it is.